# Como fazer um pop-up com texto e video do youtube?

Tags: javascript, popup, youtube

Eu preciso fazer um *pop-up* que contenha tanto texto quanto vídeo do YouTube, o problema é que o *pop-up* é bem maior que a altura da tela. Na home do site antes de clicar no link para abrir o *pop-up*, o espaço que o pop-up ocupa acaba fazendo com que a página crie um *scroll* vertical, porque ele ainda está escondido.

Já olhei em tudo quanto é site e não vi nada parecido. Encontrei só texto, só imagem ou só vídeo, ou até mesmo usando `iframe`. Mas com `iframe` eu não posso fazer.

```
<--- LINK PARA A PÁGINA --->
http://progdesenv.com.br/tapetv

<--- AQUI COMEÇA O CABEÇALHO --->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" />
<head>

<--- LINK DO JS QUE CONTROLA O POP UP --->
http://progdesenv.com.br/tapetv/js/jquery.reveal.js

</head>

<--- AQUI COMEÇA O CONTEÚDO --->
<body>
<div id="site">

    <section class="home">

        <section class="barra-topo">
    <div>
        <h1><a href="index.php" title="tapeTV">tapeTV</a></h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="quem-somos.php" class="show" data-reveal-id="pop2" title="QUEM SOMOS">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="contato.php" class="show" data-reveal-id="pop1" title="CONTATO">CONTATO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="INSTAGRAM">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="FACEBOOK">FACEBOOK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="TWITTER">TWITTER</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
        <div class="conteudo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="weddings-quem-somos.php" title="WEDDINGS">WEDDINGS</a></li>
                <li><a href="media-quem-somos.php" title="MEDIA AND MUSIC">MEDIA AND MUSIC</a></li>
                <li><a href="corporate-quem-somos.php" title="CORPORATE">CORPORATE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<--- AQUI COMEÇA O POP-UP --->

<div id="pop2" class="reveal-modal">
    <section class="cont-pop quem-pop">
        <h1></h1>
        <a href="#" title="FECHAR" class="close-reveal-modal">FECHAR</a>
        <p>undada oficialmente em 2009, a Quartel Design é uma agência mineira de comunicação visual conhecida por oferecer um “design de alto calibre”. Atualmente, a empresa conta com um jovem pelotão de integrantes que, com muito planejamento e pesquisa, elaboram projetos inovadores, dinâmicos e totalmente personalizados. Excelência e criatividade são premissas obrigatórias em cada missão executada pela tropa da Quartel Design, que acumula em seu portfólio inúmeros cases de sucesso.</p>

        <p>Missão</p>

        <p>Nossa missão é composta por três pilares:</p>

        <p>Promover diálogo fácil e trabalhar em parceria com o cliente durante todo o processo de criação;
        Desenvolver projetos originais e exclusivos de acordo com o perfil e os objetivos de cada cliente;
         Atender e superar expectativas;<br />Visão/Alvo</p>

        <p>Ampliar a atuação em diversos segmentos e tornar-se referência no país em design e desenvolvimento de websites em wordpress.</p>

        <p>Valores</p>

        <p>Excelência<br />
        Criatividade</p>
        <div class="you">
        <object width="784" height="441"><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/BCr7y4SLhck?version=3&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/BCr7y4SLhck?version=3&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="784" height="441" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
        </div>
    </section>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mostre o que você fez até agora.

Comment: Aqui está o link para ver como fica a home http://progdesenv.com.br/tapetv

Comment: Poste o código para facilite ter uma solução absoluta.

Comment: Só para complementar o problema não é o pop ficar com scroll depois de exibido e sim antes quando ainda não foi exibido

Comment: pronto postei o código, só não postei o java script por coloquei o link ali para clique

Comment: Não tenho certeza quanto a esta pergunta, mas fica a dica: o ideal é *publicar aqui* um exemplo mínimo e completo que reproduza o problema, e que os interessados em responder só tenham que copiar, colar, debugar e testar. O guia [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), em Inglês, é muito bacana.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de usar `visibility: hidden`, use `display:none`, vai tirar o *scroll* da tela.